# decoding the offset macro

Tags: c, linux, struct, macros

I was trying to understand the offset macro in c and have a problem trying to interpret this

`&((type *)0)` in

`#define offsetof(type, member) ((size_t) &((type *)0)->member)`

How do I read it. I understood the functioning but not the exact interpretation of the term.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expansion of this preprocessor macro:

```
#define offsetof(type, member) ((size_t) &((type *)0)->member)
```

Results in the following formal definition: *The `offsetof` a given `member` on a given `type` is the casting to `size_t` of the address of the `member` member for the `type` located at the null pointer address*.

Or, in other words, this is black magic that gets the address of `member` as if an object of `type` existed at the null pointer address (Note: there's no crash as long as no read or write occurs here). As the address of such a member is now absolute (relative to zero), its value can be safely casted to `size_t`, thus effectively evaluating to the offset of such a `member` as an absolute value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You run into trouble if the null pointer is not identical with the value `0`. The sandard does allow this very well. So, I'd not call it "black magic", but a "dirty (but often working) hack". Which has been supersede with C11.

Comment: @Olaf: Well, I have the same definition for both "black magic" and "dirt (but often working) hack". And you're right about the null pointer not being necessarily identical to zero. But `offsetof` is/was implementation-defined anyway, so it's assumed that in the platform the OP was investigating, the null pointer does has value zero.

Answer (score -2):

Take look at this code:

```
type *x = 0;
size_t y = &x->member;
```

Normally, `y` would be equal `x+offset`, but because `x=0`, we get only offset.

In code we write `((type *)0)` - directly returning pointer to 0 of type `type`, without creating `x` variable, then we take address of member `((type *)0)->member)`. All this is defined as `size_t` variable.